# Sum of multiplication of unequal vectors

Tags: matlab, vectorization, matrix-multiplication

I have two vectors:

```
a = [1 2 3 4 5]
b = [1; 2]
```

Every element in `a` will multiply to every element in `b`. The sum of the result is the final output. i.e.

```
a(1)*b(1)+a(1)*b(2)
a(2)*b(1)+a(2)*b(2)
a(3)*b(1)+a(2)*b(2)
a(4)*b(1)+a(4)*b(2)
a(5)*b(1)+a(5)*b(2)
```

The code should remain applicable to a large size vector. Is it possible to code without `for` loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's normal matrix multiplication combined with [`sum`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html).

```
sum((b * a).', 2)    %I'll prefer this since it uses one less transpose
```

or

```
sum(a.' * b.', 2)
```

Comment: or a golfed version: `sum(b*a).'`